# psql: sudo: unknown user "abhishek"

Tags: postgresql

I have just started with Postgresql and I know that on installation, a default user `postgres` is created. Now I have created another role/user *abhishek* with:

```
createuser --interactive
```

This role has *superuser* permission.

So I while being logged in as `postgres` added `LOGIN` role and defined the password for role `abhishek` using:

```
ALTER ROLE abhishek WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'pg13'
```

But when I try to login with this role using:

```
sudo -i -u abhishek
```

It throws the following error:

```
sudo: unknown user: abhishek
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

So any hints as to where I'm going wrong be would be welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

You created a **Postgres** user, not a Linux user. `sudo` runs a Linux command under a different Linux user account. If you want to log in to Postgres using your newly created database user, tell `psql` that:

```
psql -U abhishek <name of database to connect to>
```

Comment: Though it cleared a lot of things but I'm now getting a new error ```psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "abhishek"```

Comment: Then you need to change [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) and enable password authentication - but that is a completely different question.